# Elementary 5.1 not respecting power options on desktop/workstation

Tags: system, release-hera, suspend

I had been using Elementary 5.1 for the last two weeks on a System76 desktop/workstation. The system is fully updated/patched. For some unknown reason the system is going into sleep/suspend even when I had setup power options to ignore suspend. Defaults are suited for laptops, but for a workstation.

Is there any way to set this up. I had tried changing my settings and the lightdm user settings without any actual effect on this issue.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? If you go to System Settings --> Power, at the bottom of the screen you will see 2 buttons: Plugged In and On Battery. Click "Plugged In" What does it say next to "Suspend when inactive for"? Now click "On Battery" Now what does it say next to "Suspend when inactive for"?